# Missing sentinel in function call?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Not sure why I get "Missing sentinel in function call?"

```
NSMutableArray *kkk = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"cat", @"dog", nil];
ppp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
[ppp addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: kkk]]; // <<--- Missing sentinel in function call
[ppp addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: kkk, nil]]; //<<--- change, but it falls out

NSLog(@"Working: %@   %@", [[ppp objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:3], [[ppp objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:2] );
```

Comment: Methods that take variable arguments are known as **variadic** methods. The arguments are called as **varargs**. These kind of arguments should be terminated with a *nil* as the last argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`initWithObjects:` must be terminated with a trailing `nil`. Since it is a single object, you should be a able to use `initWithObject:`. That said, you will be leaking the array like this. Do

```
[ppp addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:kkk]];
```

There is one more problem with the piece of code here,

```
NSMutableArray *kkk = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"cat", @"dog", nil];
ppp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
[ppp addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: kkk, nil]];
```

You are creating a three dimensional array. So

```
NSLog(@"Working: %@   %@", [[ppp objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:3], [[ppp objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:2] );
```

is wrong.

```
NSLog(@"Working: %@   %@", [[[ppp objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:3], [[[ppp objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:2] );
```

should log proper values.

However if you need a two dimensional array based on your log statement, I would say you need to do this instead,

```
[ppp addObject:kkk];
```

Comment: added a line of code that was prior in the listing.  The 3 solutions you gave, none are working, unless I did something wrong... you can see the code.... thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `nil` as the last object in the list.

```
[ppp addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: kkk, nil]];
```

Basically it tells the method to stop looking for more objects. Without that, it can look at a bad pointer and crash.

Comment: @Kristen: Define *"falls out"*.